# The fundamental locus of a birational map has codimension $2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Look at the following proposition (Hartshorne Lemma V.5.1):

> Let $f:X-\rightarrow Y$ be a birational map between projective varieties, with $X$ normal. Then the locus where $f$ is not defined has codimension $2$  in $X$.

The proof shows the following thing: if $x$ is a point of codimension $1$ (I think that codimension $1$ means that $\mathcal O_{X,x}$ has dimension $1$) then $f$ is defined at $x$.

I don't understand why this fact implies the above proposition! Why if $f$ is defined at points of codimension $1$ then the fundamental locus has codimension $2$?

Answer (score 2):

You should interpret "codimension 2" here as meaning "codimension at least 2".

Of course the fundamental locus could have *higher* codimension, for example when $f$ is a morphism.

Comment: Yes you are right, I typed the theorem in a wrong way.

Comment: OK. Did that answer your question?

Comment: Why the codimension can't be 1?

Comment: That is exactly what the proof shows.  I am afraid I don't understand where the confusion is.

Comment: The proof shows that $f$ is defined at points such that dim$\mathcal O_{X,x}=1$. But I don't understand why this is in relation with the codimension in $X$ of the fundamental locus of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $U\subset X$ be the domain of $f$. Suppose $X\setminus U$ has a 1-codimensional irreducible component $V$; the proof shows that the generic point $x$ of $V$ is in $U$, which is a contradiction.